# How to set the width to auto + 5px?

Tags: html, css

I want to know that, is something like this, possible? :

```
#test{
    background-color: red;
    width:auto + 5px;
}
```

I don't want to have a `<div>`, exactly fitted with the width of the text in it. I want it to be "'text width' + 5px".

Is it possible with css?

Comment: How you will get `text-width` ? `auto` is always 100% of the parent element.

Comment: Don’t use a block element, use an inline element like `span`.

Comment: @poke: I use div, because I want to use this div, as something like a css menu button.(I don't want to use pre-built button and ...) I am not good at styling, so this was the best way in my mind to make a menu button...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using padding:

```
#test {
    background-color: red;
    width:auto;
    padding:0 5px;
}
```

This creates a padding of 5px on the right and the left side.
Top and bottom will have a padding of 0.

Comment: this does not change the width of a div, it's still 100%

Answer (score 2):

The auto width for a div is 100%. If you need only the width of its content use `float: left/right`

```
#test {
    float: left/right;
    background-color: red;
    padding-left: 5px;
    /* OR */
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use padding.

```
    #test{
        background-color: red;
        width:auto;
        padding: 0px 5px;
    }
```

Comment: this does not change the width of a div, it's still 100%

Comment: @Danny - I too saw that, and yours and Rick's answer exactly same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve like `width:auto + 5px` then you will have to use stylesheet language like `sass`, `compass` etc.

If you want to have extra spaces around your text then you can use padding as below -

```
#test {
   padding:5px;  //for all top, right, bottom, left
    OR
   padding:5px 3px; //5px for top, bottom and 3px for left right
    OR
   padding:5px 3px  4px;  //5px for top, 3px for left and right and 4px for bottom
    OR
   padding: 5px 4px 3px 2px;  //goes this way, top-right-bottom-left
}
```

Comment: I doubt sass or similar will be able to do that. It would need to be able to calculate the exact width of the text, and that completely depends on the font, the font-size, the rendering method, the zoom, etc.

Comment: There is no way known to me to get the width of the text. It is hypothetical and meaningless to talk about that.

Comment: Then why do you say that sass could do it? It’s impossible for them; if anything you could achieve such a calculation using JavaScript.

Comment: I mean't that if something you want to achieve like `x + y` then go to `sass`. and `text-width` will always remain same, no matter what is `font-size`, the bigger the text and div can't accommodate it in one line then it will wrap down.